# adding store id to product export in opencart (mysql query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

Another weird question that requires a bit of explanation, thanks in advance for the help.

I've inherited an opencart installation and I have been asked to modify a report generator (Product Export Express) which runs a big MySQL query to spit out a xls file of all the pertinent product information along with other tidbits of data.  Right now I am using the below code:

```
    <?php
ini_set("memory_limit","1G");   
class ModelInventoryExpress extends Model
{


    public function getProducts(){
        $products_sql = "SELECT
        p.product_id AS             `Product ID`, 
        p.model AS                  `Model`,
        p.sku as                    `SKU`,
        pd.name AS                  `Product Name`,
        cd.name as                  `Category`,
        p.location AS               `Location`,
        p.quantity AS               `Quanity`,
        (SELECT `text` 
        FROM product_attribute pa 
        WHERE pa.product_id = p.product_id 
        AND pa.attribute_id = 6) AS `Box Count`,

        (SELECT `text` 
        FROM product_attribute pa 
        WHERE pa.product_id = p.product_id 
        AND pa.attribute_id = 7) AS `Length`,

        (SELECT `text` 
        FROM product_attribute pa 
        WHERE pa.product_id = p.product_id 
        AND pa.attribute_id = 5) AS `Ring Gauge`,

        (SELECT `text` 
        FROM product_attribute pa 
        WHERE pa.product_id = p.product_id 
        AND pa.attribute_id = 4) AS `Strength`,

        (SELECT `text` 
        FROM product_attribute pa 
        WHERE pa.product_id = p.product_id 
        AND pa.attribute_id = 3) AS `Wrapper`,

        CASE
        WHEN p.`status` = 1
        THEN 'active'
        ELSE 'non-active'
        END  AS `Status` ,
        md.name as                  `Manufacturer`,
        FORMAT(p.price, 2) as   `Price`,
        FORMAT(p.cost, 2) as    `Cost`,
        FORMAT(p.wholesale, 2) as   `Wholesale`,                

        CASE
        WHEN pts.`store_id` = 0
        THEN 'StogieBoys.com'
        WHEN pts.`store_id` = 1
        THEN 'CigarHeist.com'
        WHEN pts.`store_id` = 2
        THEN 'm.stogieboys.com'
        WHEN pts.`store_id` = 3
        THEN 'BestCigarStuff.com'
        WHEN pts.`store_id` = 6
        THEN 'SBCigarWholesale.com'
        WHEN pts.`store_id` = 8
        THEN 'StogieTrade.com'
        ELSE 'None'
        END  AS                         `Store`,

        CASE
        WHEN p.`is_dropshipped` = 1
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END  AS                         `Is Dropshipped`        

        FROM
        product p,
        product_description pd,
        product_to_category ptc,
        category_description cd,
        manufacturer md,
        product_to_store pts
        WHERE 1
        AND p.product_id = pd.product_id
        AND p.product_id = ptc.product_id
        AND ptc.category_id = cd.category_id
        AND p.manufacturer_id = md.manufacturer_id
        AND p.product_id = pts.product_id
        ORDER BY pd.name        
         "; 
         $query = $this->db->query($products_sql);
         return $query->rows;   
    }
}
```

For the most part, this works fine.  Where it fails is the store_id portion.  The CASE will only return the first matched value, then go onto the next bit.  I need it to match and list ALL the stores that a product may show up in, same as it does for category.

When the above didn't work I tried to set it up like the AS 'category' bit like so:

```
s.name as                   `Store`,

CASE
WHEN p.`is_dropshipped` = 1
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END  AS                         `Is Dropshipped`        

FROM
product p,
product_description pd,
product_to_category ptc,
category_description cd,
manufacturer md,
store s,
product_to_store pts
WHERE 1
AND p.product_id = pd.product_id
AND p.product_id = ptc.product_id
AND ptc.category_id = cd.category_id
AND p.manufacturer_id = md.manufacturer_id
AND p.product_id = pts.product_id
AND pts.store_id = s.store_id
ORDER BY pd.name
```

But that didn't work as expected because in the store table the default store is 0 and that table starts with the other stores of a multi store set up.  I.E. 1 and so on, but doesn't list the default, or 0 store.

What would be the best way to fashion this query to get the results I'm hoping for?

Comment: Having problems understanding your logic.". I need it to match and list ALL the stores that a product may show up in, same as it does for category."  I'm assuming 'store_id' only holds one store value...are you expecting multiple rows returned per product, one for each store...or?...  (as a side note, don't let your case statements grow this big...create a reference table and join to it instead.  Easier future management there)

Comment: I wrote this on the way out the door yesterday, sorry it's a little rough to understand.  I am expecting multiple rows to be returned, one for each store.

`cd.name as                  `Category`,`

does what I am looking for.  But I could not get it to work with the store_id.  That field has a list of 5 possible numbers and null for default.  

Was that enough clarification?  I could go on for a while

Answer (score 2):

Oh man, have You ever heard about **`JOIN`** (`LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `OUTER`, ...)?

Your huge query is a very nice example of **how to do this wrong**, and here is the example of how this should be done **the right way**:

```
public function getProducts() {
    // retrieve products with basic data
    $products = $this->db->query("SELECT
    p.product_id              `Product ID`, 
    p.model                   `Model`,
    p.sku                     `SKU`,
    pd.name                   `Product Name`,
    cd.name                   `Category`,
    p.location                `Location`,
    p.quantity                `Quanity`,
    p.`status`                `Status` ,
    md.name                   `Manufacturer`,
    FORMAT(p.price, 2)        `Price`,
    FORMAT(p.cost, 2)         `Cost`,
    FORMAT(p.wholesale, 2)    `Wholesale`,                
    pts.`store_id`            `Store`,
    p.`is_dropshipped`        `Is Dropshipped`        

    FROM product p,
        LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id AND pd.language_id = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "
        LEFT JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id,
        LEFT JOIN category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id AND cd.language_id = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "
        LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
        LEFT JOIN product_to_store pts ON pts.product_id = p.product_id

    ORDER BY pd.name")->rows;

    foreach($products as $key => $product) {
        $products[$key]['Box Count']  = $this->getProductAttributeValue($product['product_id'], 6);
        $products[$key]['Length']     = $this->getProductAttributeValue($product['product_id'], 7);
        $products[$key]['Ring Gauge'] = $this->getProductAttributeValue($product['product_id'], 5);
        $products[$key]['Strength']   = $this->getProductAttributeValue($product['product_id'], 4);
        $products[$key]['Wrapper']    = $this->getProductAttributeValue($product['product_id'], 3);
    }

    return $products;   
}

public function getProductAttributeValue($product_id, $attribute_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `text` 
    FROM product_attribute pa 
    WHERE pa.product_id = " . (int).$product_id . "
    AND pa.attribute_id = " . (int)$attribute_id);

    return $query->row['text'];
}
```

As You may mention I removed all the `CASE WHEN` from SQL, as these logical interpretations of `status`, `store_id` etc. should be done in Your template or controller. SQL queries (and models) should only retrieve and store data and You should make Your SQL queries as simple as possible... Also mention the use of [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.google.com/#q=mysql+when+to+use+joins)s...

And for `0` store (that would be `NULL` or *none* value in Your products), of course display the correct store name. It is not a `0` (zero) but `NULL`, but a simple check:

```
if($product['store_id']) {
    // we have store_id
} else {
    // store_id is not set (NULL), display as the main store
}
```

would be enough here...

Comment: First, wow. Thank you, I think.  It will take me a while to go through this to make sure I understand what is happening so please be patient.  I'm still very new to SQL calls so I have heard of those, but know very little as to how they work or what they do.  I learn about the commands as I am called to use them.  As I am doing now ;-)
Second, I believe I mentioned that I inherited this, so my attempt to add the store_id to the output I was working within the existing structure, no matter how flawed.  Adding the price, cost, and wholesale is all I really did for this one, so far.

Comment: Third: Thanks again for the help.  I will be doing a little googling then testing this to see how it works.
Fourth: That if statement at the end of your helpful rant, how should that be implemented?  As 99% of the items returned will have the NULL, with many having up to 3 values.
Thanks for helping this old dog learn new tricks.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home2/theciga2/public_html/stogieboys/admin/model/inventory/express.php on line 48`
is the error that comes up when trying the code as-is.
I tried removing the . before $product in the line mentioned but all I get after that is a blank screen and nothing in the error log.  This is why I was working within the existing structure, rather than starting from scratch ;-)

Thank you for pointing out the JOIN bits, that will come in handy now that I know what it does.